# algorithm to find consecutive wins (adjusted binomial distribution)

Tags: algorithm, probability

Imagine I am having a roulette wheel and I want to feed my algorithm three integers

- p := probability to win one game
- m := number of times the wheel is spun
- k := number of consecutive wins I am interested in

and I am interested in the probability P that after spinning the wheel m times I win at least k consecutive games.

Let's go through an example where m = 5 and k = 3 and let's say 1 is a win and 0 a loss.

```
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1
```

So in my intention, this would be all solution to win at least 3 consecutive games. For every k, I have (m-k+1) possible winning outcomes.

First question, is this true? Or would also 1 1 1 0 1 and 1 0 1 1 1 be possible solutions?

Next, how would a handy computation for this problem look like? First, I thought about the binomial distribution to solve this problem, where I just iterate over all k:
\textstyle {n \choose k}\,p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}

But this somehow doesn't guarantee to have consecutive wins. Is the binomial distribution somehow adjustable to produce the output P I am looking for?

Comment: You might have better luck on [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

the following is an option you might want to consider:

you generate an array of length m, the entries 0 ...m representing the probability that at the ith time you have k-consecutive 1s.

all slots until k have probability 0, no chance for k consecutive wins.
slot k has the probability p^k.

all positions afterwards are computed based on dynamic programming approach: each position i as of position k+1 is calculated: sum consisting of position i-1  plus (p^k * (1-p) * (1 - the probability at position (i-1-k).

This way you iterate through the array and you will have in the last position the probability for at least k-consecutive 1s.

Answer (score 0):

> Or would also 1 1 1 0 1 and 1 0 1 1 1 be possible solutions?

yes, they would according to `win at least k consecutive games`.

> First, I thought about the binomial distribution to solve this problem, where I just iterate over all k: \textstyle {n \choose k}\,p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}

that might work if you combine if with acceptance-rejection method. Generate outcome from binomial, check for at least `k` winnings, accept if yes, drop otherwise.

> Is the binomial distribution somehow adjustable to produce the output P I am looking for?

Frankly, I would take a look at [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), which descirbes number of successful wins before loss (or vice versa).